How can I understand the explanation about transform-origin on MDN?
I see the following explanation about transform-origin from MDN.

In effect, this property wraps a pair of translations around the element's other transformations. The first translation moves the transform origin to the true origin at (0,0). Then the other transformations are applied, and because the transform origin is at
(0,0), those transformations act about the transform origin. Finally, the opposite translation is applied, moving the transform origin back to its original location.

I don't understand what the 'true origin' means? Based on my understanding, this document seems to be saying something like this.
.apply1 {
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

/* .apply1 is equivalent to .apply2*/

.apply2 {
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: translate(100%, 100%) rotate(45deg) translate(-100%, -100%);
}

The process for apply1 is :

set transform-origin: 0 0;
add a transform with the following steps :(1. Add a translate with the value of the origin transform-origin. (2. apply all rotate and scale transformations. (3. add a translate with the value opposite to the origin transform-origin)

I guess my understanding is correct because I can get the same result by applying apply1 and apply2. However, I don't understand how this happens. Why do these steps produce the same result as just imagining a nail fixed at the bottom right corner and then rotating the square 45 degrees?
I know my math is terrible, please forgive me...

The "true origin" is 50% 50% or the center.

Here's a step by step example showing the effect of each change and how they  compound. - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/WNqQxMM
